# How to provide a "Certificate Approver Email", for a domain not supposed to process incoming emails?

Tags: email, ssl-certificate

I am in the process of requiring the generation of a certificate on [RapidSSL](http://www.rapidssl.com/), for the domain foobar.com which hosts my web application. I've been requested to provide a "Certificate Approver Email" which (as for my understanding) should be hosted under foobar.com (say, admin@foobar.com). Problem is, I didn't plan to serve emails from any server under this domain.

Considering this "Approver Email" is an obligation on the process of certificate validation (something I am really not sure about), how can I provide a compliant email address without setting my own email server under foobar.com ?

*Note: I already have a domain (not foobar.com) with MX records pointing to google email servers to make use of google apps services, but I don't know how to make use of it to solve the problem above.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show you have nominal control of admin@foobar.com, etc., before a certificate authority will issue a certificate for that domain.  That's sort of a minimal requirement for them.

You may not be serving mail from that domain, but you can certainly configure it so that you can receive mail for that domain.  Configure Google Apps for Domains so that it knows to receive mail for foobar.com.  Google Apps has some notion of a domain alias; your main domain will be the primary, and foobar.com will be the alias.  Have admin@foobar.com go to your primary email address.  Once that's done, set up the MX record for foobar.com to point to Google, as per Google's instructions.

If you don't want to receive any mail for foobar.com, just remove the MX record once you have your SSL certificate installed.  Note that foobar.com being incommunicable probably violates someone's RFC or TOS somewhere, as I believe that the registrar likes to check on ownership information annually.

Comment: Straight directions, thanks. Now, from my quick research: Google Apps offers two ways to "fork" your main domain: a domain alias, and a secondary domain. While the domain alias seems a simpler solution, it doesn't allow the creation of email aliases under it (impossible  to create admin@foobar.com, but automatically provides ccortezia@primarydomain.com). As a solution, I had to create a secondary domain.